# Inconsistent File not Found behavior in Experience Builder site

Tags: visualforce, community-builder, experience-cloud

**note**: at time of posting, image uploading is not working.  I will try to add images later if possible.

We have built an Experience Builder site with the "Build Your Own" template.  The custom URL is just `/`, so the URL for the home page is `https://customer--partial.sandbox.my.site.com/s/`.  All pages are publicly accessible and "Public Access" is enabled in Experience Builder > Settings > General; we are not currently creating community users.

If we enter an invalid URL without the `/s` (for example, `/bad-url`), we see the Visualforce "FileNotFound" page provided by the system and configured in Setup > User Interface > Sites and Domains > Sites.  We have customized this page and would like to use it for all 404 errors.

If we enter an invalid URL with the `/s/` (for example, `/s/bad-url`), we see the "Error" page from Experience Builder (by default, a plain white page with "Invalid Page").  However, sometimes, we see the Login Error page (variant of the Login page) from Experience Builder.  It's inconsistent, and doesn't seem to be tied to the login state of a Salesforce internal user in other tabs, although browsing in an incognito window always seems to show the Error page and not the Login Error page.

Ideally, we'd like all 404s, regardless of `/s/` in the url, to show the `FileNotFound` Visualforce page.  I've tried "use custom Visualforce error pages" under Administration > Preferences, and I've tried adding a url redirect from `/s/error` (the Experience Builder error page URL) to `/FileNotFound`.

Is there some way of ensuring that all 404 errors, regardless of `/s/` in the URL, display the Visualforce error page and not a builder page?  If not, is there some way to ensure that we always serve the "Error" page and not "Login Error"?

**Update**: Conversely, if there above is not possible, but there is a way to have all 404 errors use the Experience Builder "Error" page, that would also be useful; I'd mostly like to avoid having to maintain two versions of the same thing.